# how do i secure passing variable in the url

Tags: php, url, variables, hash

how to secure your passing variables between the two pages via url? Let's assume i have a `TEST` variable in one page and i want to pass on that variable to `test2.php` page in the secure method?

How to convert `test variable` into `Hash Method` and pass on `test2.php` page via url?

**for example**

```
$test=$_POST['test']; 
echo $row['test'];

<a href="test2.php?test=$test">Test</a>

OR  

<a href="test2.php?test=$row['test']">Test</a>
```

**test2 Page**

```
$test=$_REQUEST['test'];
```

Comment: The method depends on the nature of the variable. What certain variable you want to "secure"?

Comment: You can use an ecryption/decryption function to encode the string while sending and decoding it when receiving it on the other page. The simplest is `base64_ecode/base64_decode` but it isn't secure.

Comment: use session variables and encryption and decryption methods

Comment: Who or what do you want to protect the value from, what is the purpose of the value, what is the scenario in which it is used? A value in a URL is a value in a URL, there aren't different ways of how to embed a value in a URL. But probably putting the value into a URL is not the right answer to begin with...

Answer (score 3):

By secure if you mean that you want the variable to be visible but you want to prevent users from changing the variable you can simply pass a hash along with the variable.

I.e.

```
$variable = 'abc';
$salt = 'your secret key';
$hash = md5($salt.$variable);

<a href="page2.php?variable=$variable&hash=$hash">Page 2</a>

On the second page you can rehash to see if the value has changed or not.

$variable = $_REQUEST['variable'];
$salt = 'your secret key';
$hash = md5($salt.$variable);

if($hash == $_REQUEST['hash']){
  //do staff
}
```

However this will not hide the variables from URL, you can use other suggested answers for that.

Comment: @YourCommonSense In your opinion it might be a useless thing but in my opinion it's an alternative method of doing things..It might be handy in some instances..Besides its all ready mentioned in the answer where it should be used and where not.

Comment: @YourCommonSense "if you have your variable on the second page already" Is this something that you believe? cuz this is not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not secure at all, because URLs (incl. GET arguments) are usually stored in httpd logs. So use POST for this, use SSL for transmission. If you need to use GET you can try to encrypt your data but mind that some web browsers got limits on max length of URL used, so too much data in GET may make them confused

Answer (score 1):

Secure hash functions are one way, so no good for passing values. The most secure way to do this would be to use SSL, and POST your variables so they aren't displayed in the querystring/address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Use SSL (for encrypted traffic - see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/)) and POST (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple.

- either you need that variable in the url to identify the particular page and it's content
- or it's internal site variable, like authorization information - it have to be passed via session.

For the first case you shouldn't "secure" this variable at all.